# In Android how can I design a view like the attached image?

Tags: android

I am new in android and I have a view which is in the attach image. I have to open this view after clicking on list item, but I am not finding any proper way to solve this please suggest me how can i open a dialog like in Image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check PopupWindow control in android developers, does exactly what you want. There are numerous tutorials on the web on how to customize, animate, have functionality etc. It has an onCreate method and in simple words it works just like an Activity with specific bounds. It can be attached and shown anywhere and anytime. It's actually quite useful. When you don't want to use dialogs this is the best option.